# Error #1064 mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT * from data where key="test"
```

When I run it the phpmyadmin give me the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
```

to
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key="test" LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

The type of the key column is varchar(150)

Comment: `key` is a reserved word in mySQL. Rename the column or put it in backticks ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * from data where `key`="test"
```

You shouldn't name your columns as any of the [**reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). OR at least escape them with backticks (``) in your queries when you do.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL **Key** is reserved word. So surround your column name with backticks  (`) character. Also there is no difference between single quote and double quotes in MySQL.

```
SELECT * from data where `key`='test';
SELECT * from data where `key`="test";
```

Answer (score 3):

key is a reserved word in MySQL, You need to quote it with backticks

```
SELECT * from data where `key`="test"
```

[Here is the complete list of reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)